# How to open "Finder" folder of delegate mailbox using Outlook MAPI

Tags: office365, mapi, outlook-2013

I am looking for a way to open “Finder” folder of a delegate mailbox using Outlook MAPI.

I have created EntryID of the delegate mailbox by calling CreateStoreEntryID. Using this EntryID I call OpenMsgStore which succeeded.  Now I try to open “Finder” folder which fails with error MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER. I am able to retrieve other folders like Inbox, Sent Items, etc.

```
          enum {

                         ePR_VALID_FOLDER_MASK,

                         ePR_IPM_FOLDER_ENTRYID,

                         FOLDER_NUMCOLS

          };

          SizedSPropTagArray(FOLDER_NUMCOLS, cols) = {

                         FOLDER_NUMCOLS,

                         {

                                       PR_VALID_FOLDER_MASK,

                                       PR_FINDER_ENTRYID,

                         }

          };



          ULONG pcount;

          SPropValue *props;

          hRes = pMapi_msgstore->GetProps((SPropTagArray *)&cols, 0, &pcount, &props);



          if (hRes == S_OK || hRes == MAPI_W_ERRORS_RETURNED) {

                         LONG mask;

                         if (props[ePR_VALID_FOLDER_MASK].ulPropTag != PT_ERROR)

                                       mask = props[ePR_VALID_FOLDER_MASK].Value.ul;

                         else

                                       mask = 0;

                         if ((mask & FOLDER_FINDER_VALID) &&

                                       props[ePR_IPM_FOLDER_ENTRYID].ulPropTag != PT_ERROR)

                         {

                                       hRes = **pMapi_msgstore->OpenEntry**(props[ePR_IPM_FOLDER_ENTRYID].Value.bin.cb,

                                       (LPENTRYID)props[ePR_IPM_FOLDER_ENTRYID].Value.bin.lpb,

                                       NULL,

                                       MAPI_MODIFY,

                                       &ulType,

                                       (LPUNKNOWN*)&m_lpFinderFolder);
```

Here, call to OpenEntry fails with error MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER.
Call to pMapi_msgstore -> GetProps((SPropTagArray *)&cols, 0, &pcount, &props) does not fail but &props is not correctly populated.
Is it not possible to open Finder folder of delegate mailbox ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
props[ePR_IPM_FOLDER_ENTRYID].ulPropTag != PT_ERROR)
```

needs to be changed to

```
(props[ePR_IPM_FOLDER_ENTRYID].ulPropTag & PROP_TYPE_MASK) != PT_ERROR)
```

Comment: I prefer the `PROP_TYPE` macro here. Either way, you need to do this check for every property you get from GetProps, as absent/missing properties is quite common in MAPI.